# Last changed Data with T as status in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My Data is given below

In the below sample latest record has T and last occurrence of T was updated on 3-Apr-17 so that row needs to be displayed

```
EMP     EFFDT     STATUS
11367   15-Apr-15   A
11367   14-Jun-15   A
11367   10-Aug-15   T
11367   2-Apr-17    A
11367   3-Apr-17    T *
11367   10-Apr-17   T
```

In the below sample latest record has T and last occurrence of T was updated on 23-Feb-18 so that row needs to be displayed

```
EMP     EFFDT     STATUS
20612   4-Sep-16    A
20612   23-Feb-18   T *
20612   20-Jul-18   T
```

In the below sample latest record has T and that is the only occurrence so display it

```
EMP    EFFDT      STATUS
20644   12-Jul-15   A
20644   8-Aug-16    A
20644   6-Oct-16    T*
```

In the below sample latest record does not has T so no need to display

```
EMP    EFFDT      STATUS
21155   18-May-17   T
21155   21-Jun-17   A
21155   13-Mar-18   T
21155   15-Aug-18   A
```

My Desired Output should be (* marked records)

```
EMP    EFFDT      STATUS
11367   3-Apr-17    T
20612   23-Feb-18   T
20644   6-Oct-16    T
```

Comment: So you want the previous row before the last T or the last T if only one? What if no T for the EMP ?

Comment: For an Emp if the latest EFFDT record has 'T' then it has to be considered. If is not T for the latest EFFDT it is not needed

Comment: If you see the first sample latest effdt record has T but it was actually updated on 3-Apr-17 and for the 2nd sample latest record has T but it was actually updated on 23-Feb-18 and for the 3rd sample latest record has T and that was the only update for T

Comment: English isnt my first lenguaje can you include that case in your sample data. Also include the desire output.

Comment: `was actually updated on 3-Apr-17`   what you mean? I see was update at  `10-Apr-17` too. I guess you need to clarify what update mean

Comment: My Output would be the query should fetch * Rows

Comment: Yes, but I request you add an additional case so not sure what will you show on that case. So is better you show the desire result to be more clear

Comment: 10-Aug-15 has T but after that it has changed again to A then to T on 3-Apr-17  after that no further updates are there to status

Comment: Ok, then what happen to the EMP with no T? Doesnt show or show null date?

Comment: Case 1: EMP with no 'T' for latest EFFDT record    the no need to display at all .CASE 2: If T is there for one of the rows but for the latest effdt record has A then also no need to display

Comment: You should edit your question and add those case, and add the desire output to show rows wouldn't be included

Comment: added the sample for all the cases and changed the question and added desired output

Comment: Well I already post my answer. You can update the fiddle with the new data, test it and let me know

Comment: sure and thank you so much. have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an island and gap problem.

In the cte you try to found out what island have T as last update (t=0)

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ba7dc/11)**

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT "EMP", 
         "EFFDT", 
         SUM(CASE WHEN "STATUS" <> 'T' 
                  THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END) OVER (partition by "EMP" ORDER BY "EFFDT" DESC) as t
  FROM Table1
)  
SELECT "EMP", MIN("EFFDT") as "EFFDT", MAX('T') as "STATUS"
FROM cte 
WHERE t = 0
GROUP BY "EMP"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|   EMP |                 EFFDT | STATUS |
|-------|-----------------------|--------|
| 11367 | 2017-04-03 00:00:00.0 |      T |
| 20612 | 2018-02-23 00:00:00.0 |      T |
| 20644 | 2016-10-06 00:00:00.0 |      T |
```

For debug you can try

```
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

to see how `t` values are created

Comment: can you display the output as shown in my question(edited explained the scenarios)

Comment: See that is why I request you include a desire output.as part of your question :@

Comment: sryi just added it took little time for me as i am new to stackoverflow. Would you please post your answer with the desired output please...

Comment: Done but if you cant do that for your self not sure if you are able to understand the rest of the code.

Comment: I don't think this is a gaps and islands problem; I think the OP's examples are misleading. In a sequence (from oldest to newest) of status A, A, T, A, A, T the OP will want the date of the third row (the first occurrence of T, which is then followed by two A and the very last status is T). What he explained in words was, if the last status is T and if there are any other T (didn't say anything about CONSECUTIVE), he wants that second-most-recent status of T. No gaps and islands, then.

Comment: @mathguy What I understand was he want the row with the early date for the last `T` update. So if he have three `T` he  get the early one. And each time something different to `T` appear a new island appear. Or at least that is how i saw it.

Comment: The OP may not be using English correctly either, but he may. In any case, he said if the LATEST status is T, he is then looking for the LAST occurrence of T (clearly, not the FIRST occurrence of T) - and we are lead to guess that by LAST he means LAST except for the very last one. That is what he demonstrated in the examples. In any case, not the FIRST, if there are more than two occurrences of T (and the very last one is T). More examples, with more complicated sequences, would have helped for sure.

Comment: Remember accept the answer with the green tick if solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte1
AS (
    SELECT A.*
        ,lag(STATUS, 1, 0) OVER (
            PARTITION BY EMP ORDER BY EFFDT
            ) AS PRIOR_STATUS
    FROM Table1 A
    )
SELECT EMP
    ,STATUS
    ,MAX(EFFDT) AS EFFDT
FROM cte1 A
WHERE A.STATUS = 'T'
    AND A.PRIOR_STATUS <> 'T'
GROUP BY EMP
    ,STATUS
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/458733/18

Answer (score 0):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-Mon-rr';
```

Solution (including simulated data in `with` clause):

```
with
  simulated_data (EMP, EFFDT, STATUS) as (
    select 11367, to_date('15-Apr-15'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date('14-Jun-15'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date('10-Aug-15'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date( '2-Apr-17'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date( '3-Apr-17'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date('10-Apr-17'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 20612, to_date( '4-Sep-16'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 20612, to_date('23-Feb-18'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 20612, to_date('20-Jul-18'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 20644, to_date('12-Jul-15'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 20644, to_date( '8-Aug-16'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 20644, to_date( '6-Oct-16'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 21155, to_date('18-May-17'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 21155, to_date('21-Jun-17'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 21155, to_date('13-Mar-18'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 21155, to_date('15-Aug-18'), 'A' from dual
  )
-- End of simulated data (for testing only).
-- SQL query (solution) begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select emp, min(effdt) as eff_dt, 'T' as status
from   (
         select emp, effdt, status,
                row_number() over (partition by emp, status 
                                   order by effdt desc)           as rn,
                min(status) keep (dense_rank last order by effdt)
                             over (partition by emp)              as last_status
         from   simulated_data
       )
where  last_status = 'T' and status = 'T' and rn <= 2
group by emp
;
```

Output:

```
       EMP EFF_DT    STATUS
---------- --------- ------
     11367 03-Apr-17 T
     20612 23-Feb-18 T
     20644 06-Oct-16 T
```

Explanation:

In the subquery, we add two columns to the input data. Column RN gives a rank within each partition by `EMPNO` and `STATUS`, in descending order by `EFFDT`. `LAST_STATUS` used the analytic version of the `LAST()` function to assign either `T` or `A` as the last status for each `EMP` (and it attaches this value to EVERY row for the `EMP`, regardless of each row's own `STATUS`).

In the outer query, we are only interested to retain the `EMP` where the last status was `T`. For those rows, we only want to retain the rows where the actual status of the row is in fact `T` (we know this will always include the last row for that `EMP`, by the way, and it will have `RN = 1`). Moreover, we are only interested in those rows where `RN` is 1 or possibly 2 (if there are at least two rows with status `T` for that `EMP`). Of these either one or two rows with status `T` for a given `EMP`, we want to get the EARLIEST date. That will be the ONLY date if there is no row with `RN = 2` for that partition; otherwise, it will be the date from the earlier row, with `RN = 2`.

In the outer `SELECT` we select the `EMP`, the earliest date, and the status we already know, it is `T` (so we don't need any work for this - actually it is not clear why the third column is even needed, since it is known beforehand it will be `T` in all rows).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that A and T are the only statuses, this should work.

```
WITH cte1
        AS (
            SELECT A.EMP, A.EFFDT, A.STATUS
                ,min(STATUS) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY EMP ORDER BY EFFDT RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING 
                    ) AS MIN_STATUS
            FROM Table1 A
            )
    SELECT
       cte1.EMP
      ,MIN(cte1.EFFDT) AS EFFDT
      ,MIN(cte1.STATUS) as STATUS
    FROM cte1
    WHERE cte1.MIN_STATUS = 'T'
    GROUP BY EMP
```

EDIT: well, if you have another statues, let's make it more robust. Actually, it's almost the same as juan-carlos-oropeza proposed, but he missed "RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING" part.

Ooops, it IS the same solution: juan-carlos-oropeza used order by DESC istead of unbounded following.

```
    with emp_status_log (EMP, EFFDT, STATUS) as
(
    select 11367, to_date('15-Apr-15', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date('14-Jun-15', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date('10-Aug-15', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date( '2-Apr-17', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date( '3-Apr-17', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 11367, to_date('10-Apr-17', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all

    select 20612, to_date( '4-Sep-16', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 20612, to_date('23-Feb-18', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 20612, to_date('20-Jul-18', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all

    select 20644, to_date('12-Jul-15', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 20644, to_date( '8-Aug-16', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 20644, to_date( '6-Oct-16', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all

    select 21155, to_date('18-May-17', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 21155, to_date('21-Jun-17', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual union all
    select 21155, to_date('13-Mar-18', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'T' from dual union all
    select 21155, to_date('15-Aug-18', 'dd-Mon-yy'), 'A' from dual
  )
,
-- End of simulated data (for testing only).
/* SQL query (solution) begins BELOW THIS LINE.
with--*/
cte1 as
( 
   select sl.*
     ,sum(decode(sl.STATUS, 'T', 0, 1)) OVER (
                       PARTITION BY sl.EMP ORDER BY sl.EFFDT RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING 
                       ) AS non_t_count
   from emp_status_log sl
)
select
   cte1.emp
 , min(cte1.effdt) as effdt
 , min(cte1.status) as status
from cte1
where cte1.non_t_count = 0
group by cte1.emp
```

Comment: We do have other status like R D